# Using formatter advance custom fields in zapier for date formatting

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have a field in zapier for  formatter for changing format of the date . Right now my date is in the format “31-08-2019, 3pm-6pm “
I want to format it in such a way that I am able to get the output like 
“31-08-2019 3pm “
Don’t know how to use such custom advance options 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: so it seems like you need to strip the end time (`6pm`) off of the date and then remove a comma? have you tried writing any code or tried anything else? do you always know that the input will be formatted the exact same way?

Comment: Ok so I resolved it first I separated the time from the date by creating a list and only using the first part before the ending time , in the next step I used time formatter and change the format of the time to the one that was accepted by the zapier and then in the ending time I just added a 3hr delay to the initial